# Onbeforeunload - windows assign doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to make "stay on page" button redirect to custom address. I found this code and it works in Firefox on OSX and PC, but in Chrome it doesn't do anything.

Am I missing something?

> $(document).ready(function() {
>           window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
>           location.assign('http://www.nba.com');
>           return "Play ball";
>       }
>       });

Comment: Please don't do that... Doesn't make for great user experience!! There is no standard for what you are allowed to do in onbeforeunload.

Comment: But it's a sales page so users are somewhat used to those pop up warnings. It's not redirecting them anywhere outside the side, I just want them to check out "other.html" page if they decide to close index.html

Comment: think of it this way, i am looking at buy_me.html and i don't like it so i type "google.com" into the url bar and buy_me.html loads the page buy_me.html onbeforeunload... so i close the browser but instead buy_me.html loads the page buy_me.html...

i know you aren't going to do that specifically but it is essentially what you are asking for.

when a user closes the browser window or navigates away from your page it is not possible to load a new page (unless the browser is older or hasn't wised up yet)

Answer (score 0):

if a user wants to navigate away from your page or close the browser window then all you can do is either `(1) Let Them [preferred]` or you can `(2) tap into onBeforeUnload event` which is nothing more than an "are you sure?" pop-up message allowing the user to either stay on the page or not.

your code above that says `return "Play ball"` is what determines the message to display in the "are you sure?" dialog.  if you don't return a string then you can execute clean up code before exiting without the user seeing the pop-up warning.  chrome is smart not to let window navigation code execute before the return statement.

you should definitely NOT use onBeforeUnload for page redirection / site navigation.

if you post additional code and what you are trying to accomplish there is probably a better event for you to tap into.

Comment: THere's nothing more to post, it's a basic HTML page, one wrapper DIV with info, and since it's a sales page, I would want user to have one final look at "other.html" page before they leave. I'm aware I can call a DIV out, but client's specific wish is to have another URL, "other.html" load if the user goes away from the main index.html page.